# Itemwriter is called with empty list as input

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

To quote an old question from the forum that never received an answer:

> Is it on purpose that I get an empty List as an input to the ItemWriter.write() method? In my case I have to deal with this condition because "writing nothing" leads to an error.
>   I'm using a CompositeItemProcessor where the first ItemProcessor filters out items. It may be a coindicence that the last n items get filtered so that the last input list is empty.
>
> I'd expect that write() won't get called when the input is empty - since there is nothing to write anyway. What do you think? Shall I create a ticket for that?

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/723820-itemwriter-write-gets-called-with-empty-list-as-input

I am in the exact same situation. During processing of the items it may be that every item gets filtered. In this case I would expect that `write` should not be called. Does this mean I need to guard against the case of an empty list in my writer implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell: Yes the writer can be called with an empty List.

In the processing of a chunk in [SimpleChunkProcessor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/step/item/SimpleChunkProcessor.java#L190) the processor is called for all inputs in the chunk and the result is added to outputs as seen [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/step/item/SimpleChunkProcessor.java#L297). If all items in the chunk were skipped in the processor (null was returned) then the transform method will return a chunk with an empty list of items. This output is what the writer should write and thus the writer is called with an empty list ([write](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/step/item/SimpleChunkProcessor.java#L282))

Comment: This is partially true. The usual Spring Batch tasklet chunk uses [SimpleChunkProcessor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/step/item/SimpleChunkProcessor.java) which does call the writer even if all items are filtered out by the processor. The JSR "batchlet" instead (introduced with Spring Batch 3) uses  [JsrChunkProcessor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/jsr/step/item/JsrChunkProcessor.java) -- does not.